# Are constants the only continuous functions with "symmetric derivative" zero?

Tags: real-analysis

Put precisely, if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous with 
$$
\lim_{s\to 0^+}s^{-1}(f(t+s)-f(t-s))=0 \kern20mm (*)
$$
for all $t\in\mathbb R$ , is $f$ then constant?

I guess it is but I cannot see the proof. Obviously, if instead of ($*$) we had $\lim_{s\to 0^+}s^{-1}(f(t+s)-f(t))=0$ , i.e. the right-handed derivative zero, then the assertion could be proved indirectly by a simple compactness argument applied to closed intervals $[a,b]$ with $f(a)\not=f(b)$ . However, I cannot see how this argument could be modified to get the above result. Is there possibly a reference to this, or is the result even false?

Comment: Have you tried injecting "$-f(t)+f(t)$" into the middle of your limit?

Comment: In fact, in a way, I extracted it thereof!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. See e.g. chapter 1 of *Symmetric Properties of Real Functions* by Brian Thomson.

Comment: @ Umberto P.: From http://books.google.fi/books?id=BMWk0X8rl_YC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fi&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false, I can see the table of contents. Could you please be a bit more specific? There is section 1.7 "Borel symmetric derivative". Is it possibly there?

Comment: @The-unKnowN look at Corollary 1.5 on page 7.

Comment: @ Umberto P.: I already found it! The result I need is contained in Theorem 1.4 on page 6 and Corollary 1.5 on page 7. Thanks!